# Play a sound on compile

Tags: delphi, audio, c++builder

Compiling (make or build) often takes several seconds or minutes.

I'd like to set up my IDE, RAD Studio XE2, to play a sound when it finishes compiling. Even better if I could set different sounds in case of success or failure in compilation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Beep

To get a beep when you're done building, do this:

1. Go to the project options (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Go to Build Events
3. Go to Post-Build Events/commands
4. Paste: `RunDll32.exe user32.dll,MessageBeep`

It uses rundll32.exe to directly call MessageBeep in user32.dll.
It's light-weight, and it's pretty sure that it'll work on your system.

[image: Options]

## Sample

If you want a fancy mp3 you could call winamp, or you can hack something together yourself.

## Text-To-Speech

If you're feeling more adventurous, you can let your pc talk to you when it's done building. You don't have to install anything for it; your pc already has SAPI.

The example in the screenshot tells you `Done compiling` when you're done. You can have let it tell you the build time, the output filename, etc.

Have fun! :-)

[image: Speech]

Comment: Your rundll32 approach, although it apparently works, is dangerous because `MessageBeep()` does not match the function signature that rundll32 requires for calling DLL functions. I would instead suggest having the PostBuild event execute a .bat script that uses the `start` command to play a `.wav` or other audio file instead.